# How to set the Opentok video publishing resolution

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok

I'm asking about using opentok for video publishing.

I have a problem with video resolution. To publish, i can set 2 properties: resolution and frameRate

So, in my code, I have

```
var publisherProperties = {
    insertMode: "append"
    ,width:480
    ,height:360
    ,name:'test'
    ,resolution: "1280x720"
    ,frameRate:30
};
```

var publisher = OT.initPublisher('myvideodiv', publisherProperties);

On my 2nd computer (the one catching the stream), the video looks fuzzy...

I looked up `stream.fps` and it is set to 30. But, `stream.videoDimensions` doesn't match with the resolution that I set in the publisher.

Please advice.

Comment: What do the deminsions say? Are they off by a factor or completely different?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I didn't notice someone made a comment. The dimension is completely off. I think it was 640 by something.

Comment: Is there any method for iOS to update the width and height, or specifically, the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation [here](http://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/js/reference/OT.html#initPublisher), the fuzzy video could be because of low bandwidth on your second computer. Another possible cause is that your publisher's camera might not support HD streaming. For example the 2011 macbook air's camera has a resolution of 640 x 426.

```
The published video will only use the desired resolution if the client configuration supports it.
```

Comment: Oh, I am using a mac air from 2011. That might be it. I did noticed that my client was praising on the high resolution. So, I was took by surprise.